# What is MIUI optimization?

Tags: installation, usb-debugging, miui, developer-options

In [MIUI](http://en.miui.com/) (an Android ROM), there is an option in developer settings called MIUI optimization. When this option is enabled, an app can't be installed via USB (i.e. from Android Studio).

[image]

What is the purpose of this option? And if this option is disabled, will it negatively impact the phone's performance?

Answer (score 8):

According to this [thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/redmi-note-3/how-to/guide-redmi-note-3-sd-mtk-multi-tasking-t3358433), this feature (**Turn On MIUI Optimization**)

> enables a plethora of MIUI based settings & optimizations as per the guidelines set by the MIUI developers.

**It helps to load the app and the app data in parallel reducing load times and ensuring a slicker user experience.**

However, this setting can sometimes cause a variety of issues on non-MIUI based apps such as Google Apps & Apps from Google Playstore. Users have recommended disabling the feature if you rely on Google Play Store for apps & services or use Global Stable or Global Beta MIUI ROMs.

Here is a summary of observable changes when this feature is turned on or off:

**With the MIUI Optimization Enabled, some users reported the following issues**

> - Cannot set third-party launcher like Nova, Apex or Google Now launcher.
> - Wallpaper cannot be set using in-built options via custom launchers.
> - Occasional lags, stutters or freezes while scrolling web-pages & long lists.
> - Custom apps set as default restore to default MIUI apps on reboot. (Only on MIUI China ROMs)
> - Cannot set accessibility services on reboot.
> - Background apps cannot sync data.
> - Music players stop playing after sometime.
> - UI Animations are not synced properly.

**After turning off MIUI optimization**

> - Above issues may get solved.
> - Settings → Data Usage → Graph changes to AOSP style.
> - Settings → Battery & Performance → Battery Use → Graph changes to AOSP style.
> - Settings → Installed Apps → All → Documents → It will not be disabled after every reboot.
> - Settings → Additional Settings → Buttons → Settings may get reset.
> - No OTA update notifications. Enable it to receive the OTA updates.

Comment: Is it better for global rom (MIUI) to turn the MIUI Optimization off?

Comment: @DAF  While I haven't face really big issues with the option turned on, I still feel there is no big harm to have it turned on, it is enabled by default out of the box by the manufacturer, so I prefer that it remains on, and **would recommend the same**, besides it aids in some useful enhancements of MIUI

Comment: But as explained it can have bad side effects with some Google services or if using Greenify in non root mode.

Comment: - Toggling the option will instantly reset all apps permissions to the default.
 - Reset the display DPI to the default value 392dpi

Comment: Turning off "MIUI optimization" will also make the option to have multiple user accounts available again.

Comment: According to SAI, this option (which is turned on by default BTW) also prevents it from installing split APK files, and it's true. It also claims that it will be fixed on MIUI 20.2.20. Any idea where I can read about this?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @xavier_fakerat's answer, note that the "MIUI Optimizations" prevent the installers of various applications from launching correctly even on the phone itself, rather than over-USB. If you get unexpected "Installation failed" messages (not taking about Google Play Store; I never use that) - it might be a conflict between the installer and the MIUI optimization mechanism.